# Passing python dict to template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

There has to be a way to do this... but I can't find it.

If I pass one dictionary to a template like so:

```
@app.route("/")
def my_route():
  content = {'thing':'some stuff',
             'other':'more stuff'}
  return render_template('template.html', content=content)
```

This works fine in my template... but is there a way that I can drop the 'content.' , from

```
{{ content.thing }}
```

I feel like I have seen this before, but can't find it anywhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a duplicate... Stretching it, yes, but come on... overzealous duplicate-designators...

Comment: how does `template.html` look like?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try

```
return render_template('template.html', **content)
```

Answer (score 25):

You need to use the `**` operator to pass the `content` dict as keyword arguments:

```
return render_template('template.html', **content)
```

This is effectively the same as passing the items in the dict as keyword arguments:

```
return render_template(
    'template.html',
    thing='some stuff',
    other='more stuff',
)
```